# How can I change 5 to 4 columns and keep them centred in HTML?

Tags: html, css

I'm editing a bootstrap responsive template to fit my needs. My HTML/CSS knowledge is limited and I'm stuck here:

I need 4 columns (with the 4 first contacts) on the first row and the other 3 (with the remaining 3 contacts) on the 2nd row. Any advice?

P.S - In the end I need them all centred in the page.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/2.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- Five columns -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="span2 offset1">
    <div class="teamalign">
      <img class="team-thumb img-circle" src="img/portrait-1.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <h3>Marta Silva</h3>
    <div class="job-position">CEO</div>
  </div>
  <!-- ./span2 -->
  <div class="span2">
    <div class="teamalign">
      <img class="team-thumb img-circle" src="img/portrait-2.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <h3>Eliana Neto</h3>
    <div class="job-position">CFO</div>
  </div>
  <!-- ./span2 -->
  <div class="span2">
    <div class="teamalign">
      <img class="team-thumb img-circle" src="img/portrait-3.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <h3>Carlos Martins </h3>
    <div class="job-position">Supervisor Operations</div>
  </div>
  <!-- ./span2 -->
  <div class="span2">
    <div class="teamalign">
      <img class="team-thumb img-circle" src="img/portrait-4.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <h3>Pedro Correia</h3>
    <div class="job-position">HR & Training</div>
  </div>
  <!-- ./span2 -->
  <div class="span2">
    <div class="teamalign">
      <img class="team-thumb img-circle" src="img/portrait-5.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <h3>Luis Vicente</h3>
    <div class="job-position">Iberia Supervisor</div>
  </div>
  <!-- ./span2 -->
  <div class="span2">
    <div class="teamalign">
      <img class="team-thumb img-circle" src="img/portrait-6.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <h3>Nuno Figueiredo</h3>
    <div class="job-position">U.K Supervisor</div>
  </div>
  <!-- ./span2 -->
  <div class="span2">
    <div class="teamalign">
      <img class="team-thumb img-circle" src="img/portrait-7.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <h3>Ana Veríssimo</h3>
    <div class="job-position">Benelux & Germany Supervisor</div>
  </div>
  <!-- ./span2 -->
</div>
```

Comment: See you cannot align 4 in one and three in the other... But centring it will be possible.

Comment: @chipChocolate.py That's bootstrap 2.

Comment: OK, but how can I insert a break on the 4th one and put the 5th on the 2nd row? Right now they appear 5 on the 1st row and 2 on the 2nd row.

Comment: Ah sorry, didnt saw it. It worked, thanks!
But now they dont have the same space between them in the 2nd row. Any advice?

Comment: This is the output: http://jsbin.com/fareburoca/edit?html,output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use this way:

- Wrap the first row items in `.span3`s.
- Wrap the second row items in `.span4`s.

Use the full screen preview and see for yourself. Let me know if this is what you wanted.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/2.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <!-- Five columns -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="span3">
      <div class="teamalign"> <img class="team-thumb img-circle" src="img/portrait-1.jpg" alt=""> </div>
      <h3>Marta Silva</h3>
      <div class="job-position">CEO</div>
    </div>
    <!-- ./span2 -->
    <div class="span3">
      <div class="teamalign"> <img class="team-thumb img-circle" src="img/portrait-2.jpg" alt=""> </div>
      <h3>Eliana Neto</h3>
      <div class="job-position">CFO</div>
    </div>
    <!-- ./span2 -->
    <div class="span3">
      <div class="teamalign"> <img class="team-thumb img-circle" src="img/portrait-3.jpg" alt=""> </div>
      <h3>Carlos Martins </h3>
      <div class="job-position">Supervisor Operations</div>
    </div>
    <!-- ./span2 -->
    <div class="span3">
      <div class="teamalign"> <img class="team-thumb img-circle" src="img/portrait-4.jpg" alt=""> </div>
      <h3>Pedro Correia</h3>
      <div class="job-position">HR & Training</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <!-- ./span2 -->
    <div class="span4">
      <div class="teamalign"> <img class="team-thumb img-circle" src="img/portrait-5.jpg" alt=""> </div>
      <h3>Luis Vicente</h3>
      <div class="job-position">Iberia Supervisor</div>
    </div>
    <!-- ./span2 -->
    <div class="span4">
      <div class="teamalign"> <img class="team-thumb img-circle" src="img/portrait-6.jpg" alt=""> </div>
      <h3>Nuno Figueiredo</h3>
      <div class="job-position">U.K Supervisor</div>
    </div>
    <!-- ./span2 -->
    <div class="span4">
      <div class="teamalign"> <img class="team-thumb img-circle" src="img/portrait-7.jpg" alt=""> </div>
      <h3>Ana Veríssimo</h3>
      <div class="job-position">Benelux & Germany Supervisor</div>
    </div>
    <!-- ./span2 -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Now "contacts" on the second row don't have the same space between them (like in the 1st row). Any advice?

Comment: @Pumizo You can make them `display: inline-block` and remove the `float` and use `text-align: center`.

Comment: I understood you output at jsbin but my knowledge doesn't allow me to apply it. Can you please instruct how to do it in more detail?

Comment: @Pumizo You just need to copy the CSS part and add it in your CSS file and change the HTML like how it is on the left side. Simple. Let me know if you are facing any issues.

Comment: The final result fixes the space between all "contacts" on both rows but aligns them all to the left side. It also changed the font type on each "contact"

Comment: @Pumizo Did you give the `text-center` or `text-align: center`?

Comment: shall I put it only at style.css or also in stylepages.css?

Answer (score -1):

Try the following code, i hope that will work.

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="teamalign"><img class="team-thumb img-circle" src="img/portrait-1.jpg" alt=""></div>
      <h3>Marta Silva</h3>
      <div class="job-position">CEO</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="teamalign"><img class="team-thumb img-circle" src="img/portrait-1.jpg" alt=""></div>
      <h3>Marta Silva</h3>
      <div class="job-position">CEO</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="teamalign"><img class="team-thumb img-circle" src="img/portrait-1.jpg" alt=""></div>
      <h3>Marta Silva</h3>
      <div class="job-position">CEO</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="teamalign"><img class="team-thumb img-circle" src="img/portrait-1.jpg" alt=""></div>
      <h3>Marta Silva</h3>
      <div class="job-position">CEO</div>
    </div>
  </div><!-- ./row -->

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="teamalign"><img class="team-thumb img-circle" src="img/portrait-1.jpg" alt=""></div>
      <h3>Marta Silva</h3>
      <div class="job-position">CEO</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="teamalign"><img class="team-thumb img-circle" src="img/portrait-1.jpg" alt=""></div>
      <h3>Marta Silva</h3>
      <div class="job-position">CEO</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="teamalign"><img class="team-thumb img-circle" src="img/portrait-1.jpg" alt=""></div>
      <h3>Marta Silva</h3>
      <div class="job-position">CEO</div>
    </div>
  </div><!-- ./row -->

</div><!-- ./container -->
```

Comment: This didn't worked right. With this I have one "contact" on each row (total 7 lines and 1 column)!

This is your result: https://jsbin.com/recumu

Comment: This will never work because OP is using BS 2 and your example is on BS 3. Please check before answering.

Comment: Sorry, maybe i did not understand your query properly. I have tested the code myself and so far i understand its working well. However, I hope you got the solution for another developer, so not checking that again. But if you still need help, don't hesitate to leave comment here :)